# Flash buttons: get the frame label?

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript

Is there any way to click on a button (or movieclip) in Flash and somehow get the current framelabel that the instance happens to be on?

```
my_button_instance.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickInstance, false, 0, true);

private function clickInstance(e:MouseEvent):void {
   trace(trace-out-the-frame-label-here?);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this url maybe it is helpful : http://webdesigner-freelancer.com/en/entry/frame-labels-in-timeline-animation-using-as3/

change

`if(event.target.currentLabel == ”endframe”){...`

to

`trace(event.target.currentLabel)`